# Don't edit German tags to English tags

Tags: discussion, tags, language

In the question

[Gibt es einen Grund, warum das Antwortwort zu „wie“, nämlich „so“, nicht mit D beginnt?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/gibt-es-einen-grund-warum-das-antwortwort-zu-wie-namlich-so-nicht-mit-d-be)

I used the tag "Fragewörter" which is rendered "frageworter".

Among other several useful edits, this tag was edited to "interrogatives".

I don't think that German tags should be edited, they should be synonymed, so that writers of German posts can use German tags that are auto-completed and then automatically converted to the English equivalent. Unfortunately, I do not have the rights to just generate German synonyms for every tag, so the only way to go is to use the German tags first. If you know a better way that's fine, but I think that manually editing the tags is not very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that they should be synonymed, but don't see any problem in editing the tags manually until enough synonym votes have been cast.

Comment: That's fine, I couldn't see the synonym proposals before, but now I can, I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

Ich habe eben nach "Redensart" gesucht, und nichts gefunden. Diese Synonymisierung scheint nicht zu klappen, und damit müssen Chinesen, Japaner, Franzosen und Deutsche Englisch lernen, um die Seite benutzen zu können. Das ist absurd!

Als besonders hinderlich erweist sich, dass man eine hohe Reputation benötigt, um ein Synonym vorzuschlagen, und bezüglich des Synonyms eine Mindestpunktzahl oder eine Mindestzahl an gewerteten Beiträge, dass man aber auch nur existierende Tags zur Synonymisierung vorschlagen kann.

Das Löschen dt. Schlüsselwörter vereitelt daher die Synonymisierug.

Die Tags sollten Deutsch sein, so dass man die Seite ohne Englischkenntnisse uneingeschränkt benutzen kann.

Sprachunterricht findet auch immer in der zu lernenden Sprache statt.

---

I recently searched for *Redensart*, without success. The synonym system seems not to work.

The first problem is, that you need much (1250?) reputation to suggest a synonym, but to mark something as a synonym, it has to exist as a tag before.

Then you need a score of 5 in this tag to suggest a synonym.

Tags should be preferably in German, so that you can use the page without restriction without English knowledge.

Excercises in a language ususally happen int that language too.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to display each tag with names in both languages. Renaming the tags like that in the current system won't be able to accomplish that, as their length is limited and as there'd be problems to distinguish between word separators and language separators. But I think with some not-so-major changes to the software, this could be enabled: [Zweisprachige Tags oder zweisprachig angezeigte Tags - bilingual tags or bilingually displayed tags](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497/22560)

---

Eine Mögliche Lösung könnte sein, jeden Tag mit Namen in beiden Sprachen anzuzeigen. Tags entsprechend umzubenennen, ist leider derzeit nicht so einfach möglich, da einerseits die Länge der Tag-Namen begrenzt ist und man andererseits ein Problem hätte, Wort-Trennzeichen von Sprach-Trennezeichen zu unterscheiden. Ich glaube aber, dass mit nicht allzugrossen Änderungen an der Stack-Exchange-Software solche zweisprachigen Tags ermöglicht werden könnten: [Zweisprachige Tags oder zweisprachig angezeigte Tags - bilingual tags or bilingually displayed tags](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497/22560)