# What English tag could be used as a synonym for "Satzteilkonjunktion"?

Tags: discussion, tags

For a few days we have a new tag [satzteilkonjunktion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satzteilkonjunktion) used on 3 questions with the following information fields:

> Questions on conjunctions that connect constituents of sentences (in constrast to sentences or subclauses).
>
> *Satzteilkonjunktionen are ’conjunctions of constituents’ forming conjunctional phrases (Konjunktionalphrasen) within clauses. This is in contrast to the use as subordinating conjunctions and prepositions respectively. This type of conjunction is also called Adjunktor in newer German word-type classifications. Examples of such conjunctions are als, wie, statt, and außer.*

As we agreed to [only have English tags](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in) and to [synonymize German tags to their English counterpart](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/dont-edit-german-tags-to-english-tags) we are looking for a good English tag that could be used as a target for *Satzteilkonjunktion*.

Any suggestions are welcome (please write answers not comments to let the community vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar))

(This is the interwiki lemma for [deWP's Konjunktion_(Wortart)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_(Wortart)). Given the context of this SE, I think that would be both a sufficient and good choice.)

Answer (score 0):

phrase-conjunction

(This is a naive 1:1 transliteration of the original tag components.)

Comment: Gibt es das, bzw. ist das ein etablierter Begriff, den auch andere Benutzer benutzen werden?

Comment: @Takkat siehe edit und neue Antwort ;)